# Make .card-title background extend to border (no padding)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a simple bootstrap `.card` and am unsure how to make the `.card-title` `background` extend to the edges of the `border`. The code is below and an example can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/x6pmLk8c/

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <style>
  .card{
    border: 1px solid black; /* set for visual purposes */
   }
  .card-title{
    background: blue;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>    
 <div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
   <h3 class= 'card-title text-center mb-2'>Title</h3>
   <div class= 'card-text'>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    veniam perspiciatis repellendus eligendi, dicta facere libero illum sed eum
    atque culpa facilis iure, hic maiores. Saepe cum illum, eaque!
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

It appears there is some padding between `.card`'s contents and its `border`. I have tried

```
.card,
.card-title{
    padding: 0;
}
```

but this had no effect. Does anyone know how to correct this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please cut and paste `<h3 class= 'card-title text-center mb-2'>Title</h3>` outside of 
`<div class="card-body">` **the new code structure is:**

```
<div class="card">
   <h3 class="card-title text-center mb-2">Title</h3>
   <div class="card-body">
       <div class="card-text">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo necessitatibus veniam perspiciatis repellendus eligendi, dicta facere libero illum sed eum atque culpa facilis iure, hic maiores. Saepe cum illum, eaque!
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Rahul, didn't realize this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `.card-body` is set with some initial padding.

```
.card-body{
  padding: 0;
}
```

Fixed this problem.